# Conditional statements with too many ifelse statements

Tags: r, if-statement

I have the following data:

```
my.list<-list(a=c(55,17,18,18,18,21),
b=c(11,17,17,17,22,18,22),
c=c(55,17,22,22,22,22,22,21,30))    

x<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)    

set.seed(1)    

my.function <- function(x) {

ifelse(x == 1,sample(my.list$a,replace = T),
ifelse(x == 2,sample(my.list$b,replace = T),
ifelse(x == 3,sample(my.list$c,replace = T)


)))    
}        

p<-sapply(x, my.function)
```

In the "real" dataset I have much more ifelse-statements than shown above and the code is too long.

Is there a smarter solution so I don't need to write so many ifelse-statements? Every ifelse-statement is related to a unique list as above with different lengths that I draw samples from.

Comment: `Map(function(l,x) sample(l[[x]]), list(my.list), x)` ? I'm not sure why you're getting only a vector of length 15 as a result though. That seems really odd considering you take a sample the same length of each `my.list` `list`.

Comment: `ifelse` only returns single values for each comparison, so you may not be getting what you expect - `ifelse(c(1,1,2)==1, 1:10, 10:1)` for example.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you'd like this function to return.  Do you want a vector of single draws from your list, or a list of full resamples from your list?

Answer (score 0):

That double use of `x` confused me a bit. If I understand you correctly,

```
my.function <- function(x) {
   sample(my.list[[1]],size = 1,replace = T)
}
```

should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

To avoid the oddities of `ifelse()` that @thelatemail pointed out and to avoid reliance on the global environment, I'd propose

```
my.list<-list(a=c(55,17,18,18,18,21), b=c(11,17,17,17,22,18,22), c=c(55,17,22,22,22,22,22,21,30))    

x<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)    

set.seed(1)    

my.function <- function(x, list) {
  sample(list[[x]], replace = T)
}        

p<-sapply(x, my.function, list=my.list)
```